# Http redirect for content on relative paths

Tags: html, http

Essentially what my use case is, a 3rd party server only support POST on a specific integration url. but I want a browser to hit it from a normal html link (I have no control over either systems code, I can only configure the destination url for the link)

To solve or this I have written a web hosted app (done in Mirth Connect - but the server tech in theory shouldn't matter). The objective of my app is to cat the GET and convert it to a POST

My systems logic:
My web server receives an HTTP GET from a browser, grabs the query strings.
The server then performs an HTTP POST on a 3rd party server, and grabs the html result
The server then returns the original html and delivers it as the result to the original http request from the browser

This works great, the issue comes in with content hosted on the 3rd party server that is referenced with a relative path (css, js, images, etc).

Because I have "tricked" the browser into thinking it received the html from my system, it looks on my server for the content (which will all 404).

Without having to handle the fetching of all the content myself, is there a way to tell a browser to redirect all further queries to the 3rd party server?

I tried making my HTTP GET return a status 301 or 302 with the location being the base address of the 3rd party server, but this obviously tells the browser to redirect completely

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

I just had to intercept the html and inject a BASE tag .